# Displays categories and sub categories (Laravel Blade)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

i have problem with display category and subcategories , i made this
in my blade

```
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><b class="fa fa-home"></b> Начало</a></li>
                @foreach ($categories as $cat)
                    @foreach($subcategories as $sub)

                        @if($sub->parent_id == $cat->id)
                            <li class="dropdown ">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    {{$cat->name}} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('category/'.$sub->slug) }}">{{ $sub->name }}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It show categories only when have one subcategory, i don't know why happend! Someone help me! (No bad votes please)

Here is my variables:

```
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', NULL)->get();
    $subcategories = Category::where('parent_id','!=',NULL)->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you only create the list item within your foreach loop when there is a sub category aswell.

This example should do the trick for you.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><b class="fa fa-home"></b> Начало</a></li>
        @foreach ($categories as $cat)
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{$cat->name}} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>
            @foreach($subcategories as $sub)
                @if($sub->parent_id == $cat->id)
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ url('category/'.$sub->slug) }}">{{ $sub->name }}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

It is untested so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it works great, but it have caret down on every category name, i try to remove it but , it change it along with subcategory and this happend: http://prntscr.com/k5pz40, it have in normal category dropdown class , i don't wanna this :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with little changes, but now work thanks @answered26

Here is my changes

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><b class="fa fa-home"></b> Начало</a></li>
                @foreach ($categories as $cat)
                    <li class="{{ $cat->children->count() > 0 ? 'dropdown' : ''}}">
                        <a href="#" class="{{ $cat->children->count() > 0 ? 'dropdown-toggle' : ''  }}" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            {{$cat->name}} {!! $cat->children->count() > 0 ? '<b class="fa fa-caret-down"></b>' : '' !!}
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @foreach($subcategories as $sub)
                            @if($sub->parent_id == $cat->id)
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('category/'.$sub->slug) }}">{{ $sub->name }}</a></li>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If this is the best solution, help future researchers to find it by dignifying it with the green tick.  If the other answer was helpful, give it an upvote.  Please clean up your question by removing unnecessary lines of code, capitalizing the word "i", removing your request to discourage downvotes, and keep tabbing in your code to a minimum to reduce horizontal scrolling.  If you wish to avoid dowvotes (and have a chance of upvotes), be sure to include EXACTLY what your error/issue is and explain your EXACT desired output -- in the question, not via comments.